# TFS email notfication to non team members

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to send an email notification to a non member team user.

I have some customers to send requirements to us and want to send email alerts to them for any changes on that requirements.

I was trying to add his email manually at send mail screen, but it told me that isn't a valid member

How can I do to send personalized emails to a non team member in TFS ?

Note: I'm using TFS 2017

Answer (score 1):

A possible way would be to set a notification for you first, and afterwards (that particular notification, that would like to go to your customer) add their e-mail addresses as well like:

[image]

It does even work for me, when creating a new notification, for a failed build for example, to directly change the e-mail where I would to receive the notification, by clicking on the "Edit..." from SendTo option:

[image]

I have tried that in TFS 2017 RTM as well.

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the subscriptions for the requirements?

Based on my test, we can enter the email addresses directly when create the subscription and it works as expected. (`Deliver To: Team email address` )

In this case, you need to make sure your SMTP server can reach to the customers' email address, you can `Send Test Email` from TFS Administration Console to check that. If the customers can receive the test email, then you can enter the email addresses directly in subscription.

If the SMTP server can not reach to the customers' email address, then as a workaround you can forward the alert emails as Danko mentioned above. Just set a notification for you first, then set forward rules, thus the notification emails will automatically forward to customers once you the requirements changed.

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

Filter by Tags only available in workitem queries. It's not available in notification subscriptions filter.

However you can filter by other existing fields there, e.g `Description contains xxx`, `Title contains xxx`. Just add the corresponding values (`xxx`) in the fields of the requirements. You can even [custom a new field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/add-modify-field) to filter there.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I'm newer to TFS, And can´t found where to add Suscriptions, where is it ?

Comment: I see it now. But there is no place to filter for example **By Tag Name** Actually we are tagging specific requirements with the customer's name, I don't want to send all notifications to all customers Just those ones where a specific customer is interested it..

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Filter by Tags only available in workitem querys. It's not available in notification subscriptions. However you can filter by other existing fields there, e.g `Description contains xxx`, `Title contains xxx`. Just add the corresponding values (`xxx`) in the fields of the requirements.

Comment: Ok.. tks again, tag is more accurate. Some one could make typos on texts. But I'm going to try it.

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez Yeah, tag should be more accurate, unfortunately it's not supported. I tried the workaround mentioned above, it works for me. So, just have a try with that.